# How to create an equation from this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

A full cola bottle is $2.

2 caps can be exchanged with 1 full cola bottle.

4 empty bottles can be exchanged with 1 full cola bottle.

If you have $20, how many full coke bottles you will totally get?

The answer is 35 bottles by drawing all the possibilities.

But what I want to know with this problem is how to create an equation for shortcut solving.

The equation seems to be y=2x-5 when x is the amount of dollars you have and y is the totally amount of coke you will get but I want to know how to proof this. And I want to know how to create this equation from scratch, I got this equation from try changing the amount of money I have and drawing all the possibilities and I saw this relationship.

Comment: Does an empty cola bottle need its cap to be exchanged?

Comment: Yes, all caps and bottles can be exchanged if you have enough of them.

Comment: Okay, more explicitly:  does "empty bottle" mean "including cap" such that the cap cannot be separately exchanged, or does it mean "independent of cap" such that four empty bottles can be turned in for one full, and their caps can be turned in for two full, for a total of three full bottles from the original four bottles?

Comment: Empty bottle doesn't need its cap to exchange for full cola bottle. E.g. if you have 2 caps and 4 empty bottles you can exchange for 3 more full cola bottle. And you can exchange more because you have 3 caps and 3 bottles left.